# Correlation coefficients for spatial polygons data frame

Tags: polygon, spatial, correlation, coefficients

I have a spatial polygons data frame and I am interested in a matrix of correlation coefficients for my variables. 
The command

```
    >cor(df)
```

returns the following error:

```
    >Error in cor(MergedData) : supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix-like 'x'
```

I can get pairwise coefficients if I run the following command

```
    >cor.test(df$var1, df$var2)
```

However, since I have 15 variables, I would need to run over 200 commands. Is there a way I could do it faster, i.e. return a matrix of correlation coefficients all in one table?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`cor` only works on data frames or matrices. You need to pull out the *data* slot from the `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`:

```
grd <- GridTopology(c(1,1), c(1,1), c(10,10))
polys <- as(grd, "SpatialPolygons")
centroids <- coordinates(polys)
x <- centroids[,1]
y <- centroids[,2]
z <- 1.4 + 0.1*x + 0.2*y + 0.002*x*x
ex_1.7 <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(polys,
                                   data=data.frame(x=x, y=y, z=z, row.names=row.names(polys)))

class(slot(ex_1.7, "data"))
cor(slot(ex_1.7, "data"))
```

Example `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` from the docs at:
`` ??sp::`SpatialPolygonsDataFrame-class` ``